# ¿Cómo puedo importar un módulo de una subcarpeta desde otra subcarpeta en python?

Tags: python, jupyter

hola a todos lo que necesito es importar desde archivo1 lo que se encuentra en archivo2, alguien puede indicarme como hacerlo, gracias:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
import os, sys, inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir) + "\\subcarpeta2\\"
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir) 

import archivo2
```

El string 'parentdir' tendrá la ruta absoluta a la "subcarpeta2" y la siguiente línea de código incluye éste path al PATH del sistema de forma temporal para buscar módulos. La siguiente línea te podrá marcar un error pues no encuentra el módulo que quieres en el path del script que estás usando (por lo menos a mí me marcó ese error), pero igual puedes ejecutar tu código y ver que funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciona perfectamente